# rotate vector around a point using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Im trying to rotate a vector around a point.
For this example lets say i want to rotate 30 degrees around point 2,3
I learned that it takes 3 steps

**1. move vector using a "move matrix".**

so the matrix would  look like:

*(matrix 1)*

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**2. rotate using a rotation matrix**

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
.866& -.5& 0\\
.5& .866& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 **3. move back using a "move matrix" (same as matrix one using negative values for x and y):**

*(matrix 3)*

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

But I don't understand how I should do these steps.
Should I multipy matrix one with matrix two, the result of this with matrix 3 and the result of that with my input, or the input with the result?

Or should I take my input, multiply with matrix 1, multiply the result with matrix 2 and after that multiply that result with matrix 3? I understand the steps but im not sure how to use these steps (if that makes sense).

edit:

lets call my input *i*

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

should I do

$$
   m1 * m2 * m3*  i
$$

or

$$
i * m1 * m2 * m3
$$
or
$$
(i * m1)   * (i * m2) * (i * m3)
$$

*If anyone is able to find a link to a solved transformation that would be incredible helpfull, that way I can check if im doing it correctly.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x-2\\ y-3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}(x-2)\cos 30 - (y-3)\sin 30\\ (x-2)\sin 30+ (y-3)\cos30\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}(x-2)\cos 30 - (y-3)\sin 30+2\\ (x-2)\sin 30+ (y-3)\cos30+3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Alternatively,

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 2\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 3\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& -2\cos 30 + 3\sin30+2\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& -2\sin 30 - 3\cos 30 +3\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
x\cos 30 -y\sin 30 -2\cos 30 + 3\sin30+2\\
x\sin 30 +y\cos 30 -2\sin 30 - 3\cos 30 +3\\
 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(x-2)\cos 30 - (y-3)\sin 30+2\\ (x-2)\sin 30+ (y-3)\cos30+3\\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Im trying to find the solution for x=6 y=8. First i tried http://www.nh.cas.cz/people/lazar/celler/online_tools.php?start_vec=6,8,1&rot_ax=2,3,1&rot_ang=30   which gives me (x = 5.236151, y = 8.524953, z = 0.95284) see http://imgur.com/a/kyM3g, Than i tried using google calculator for x "(6−2)cos(30)−(8−3)sin(30)+2" which gave me 7.55716392001. For y "(6−2)sin(30)+(8−3)cos(30)+3" I got -0.180869. Could you add one solved version (so ending with 3 numbers (xyz) so I and others can see what  the output should be (xy dosnt mather) as long as i can test if im calculating it right.

Comment: Neither are correct.  At least not the way you have asked it.  The second one is closer, but you have used calculated in radians when I think you want degrees.  The second one has you rotating in three dimensions around an axis that is not perpendicular to the xy plane.  Which is the way you have phrased the question.

Comment: my bad with degrees i get 2.964101615136 and
9.33012701892. Thanks a ton for your help so far, Im trying to make a program to do this calculation but I can't find the outcome to expect to check my program.

Comment: I agree with those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is write your vector as 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then you apply the three matrices one after the other (it doesn't matter if you apply them one by one, or if you apply them to the resulting vector; the only important thing is that you respect the order: first goes right).

So you want to calculate 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The order is the opposite you wrote, but you need to apply first the subtraction of $(2,3)$ to move things to the origin, then rotate, and then move back to $(2,3)$.

Comment: dumb question "the only important thing is that you respect the order: first goes right" do you mean I should multiply (x,y,1) * (matrix with negative values)  first?

Comment: The matrix with the negative values (2,3) to (0,0).  That is the first think you need to do.  And that is why it is on the right.  Since matrix multiplication is associative, once you have set it up correctly, you can then proceed to multiply in any order you choose.

Comment: @DougM I still dont get it, let call the matrices posted by martin 1,2,3,4 so i first do 1*2. the result *3, that result *4. What confuces me is "First goes right". so should i do the right multiplication first as in 3 *4 than the result *2 than the result *1.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Matrix multiplication is associative. (( (1*2)*3)*4) or (1*2)*(3*4) or 1*(2*(3*4))).  First goes right is important in the set up, not in the multiplication.

Comment: @DougM I've added a bounty because i cant find any worked out version to check if im doing it correctly right now. If you could add one example im very happy to accept as an answer and reward the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix operations are linear and translation is not. I can't understand why you use moving matrix (go to 3-d spaces for something like that).

Anyway if you have to do something like that: The Doug M. answer is correct.

$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\ y'\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 30& -\sin 30& 0\\
\sin 30& \cos 30& 0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\ 0&1&-3\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

The order of opperations is irrelebant: matrix multiplication is associative.